# Angular Deleting Items from Database But Displaying Empty Object on Front End

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular app that reads, creates, updates and deletes listings for sale.  I am able to delete items from the database, using Postman, (as I haven't set up the delete functionality on the front end yet).  However, on the front end, my items are being retrieved from the database, but it seems two additional empty objects are being displayed as well.  Those were items I deleted on the backend using Postman. I tried using ngIf to check for non-zero values and that works but the content box is still being displayed.  I know I need a way to do a check before the content box is drawn but I'm not sure how. I know this is an easy one, I'm just not thinking of it at the moment...Thanks, Ironman

**listing-page.component.html**

```
    <div>
        <div class="content-box" *ngFor="let listing of listings">
            <a *ngIf="!listing.price == 0" routerLink="/listings/{{listing.id}}">
                <h3>{{listing.name}} - ${{listing.price}}</h3>
    
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**deleteListings.js**

```
import { db } from '../database';

export const deleteListingRoute = {

    method: 'DELETE',
    path: '/api/listings/{id}',
    handler: async(req, h) => {
        const {id} = req.params;
        await db.query(
            'DELETE FROM listings WHERE id=?',
            [id],
        );

        return { message: 'Succes!'};
    }
}
```

**listings.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Listing } from './types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListingsService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }


  getListings(): Observable<Listing[]>{
    return this.http.get<Listing[]>('/api/listings');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show more code. Where is you api call? where is delete function? Does api retun you empty object or they only exist in angular?

Comment: @PanterP I will update the question with the code you inquired about.  Thanks.

Comment: you have ngForon class="content-box". That why ngIF dont work. Add content-box inside ngFor  <div *ngFor="let listing of listings">
<div class="content-box" >
        <a *ngIf="!listing.price == 0" routerLink="/listings/{{listing.id}}">
            <h3>{{listing.name}} - ${{listing.price}}</h3>

        </a>
</div>
    </div>

Comment: @PanterP I've added the delete listing functionality (deleteListings.js) and the api call (listings.service.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question, I Believe in your delete functionality of backend you just updating it's price to `0`, Normally If you had deleted the item from backend then no need retrieve those deleted items again,

However, If I assume that your deleted Item has 0 price, then try to filter the list before render to Frontend, Like below

```
let listings = [
  {id: 1, price: 1000, name: "Keyboard"},
  {id: 1, price: 500, name: "Mouse"},
  {id: 1, price: 0, name: "Handfree"},
  {id: 1, price: 0, name: "Cover"}, 
  {id: 1, price: 1500, name: "Other"},
]

listings = listings.filter(o => o.price>0);
```

Or I have modified above html code, Please have a look below

```
<div *ngFor="let listing of listings">
    <div class="content-box" *ngIf="!listing.price == 0">
        <a  routerLink="/listings/{{listing.id}}">
            <h3>{{listing.name}} - ${{listing.price}}</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Suneel for taking the time to help out.  I will try your solution in about an hour and I'll get back to you.  Again many thanks.

Comment: Suneel I have added the delete listing code and the api code in the service.

Comment: I Checked your code, it's Good, delete functionality removing the item from table, So, I think those item, who's price is `zero (0)`, you don't want to display right? In this case you can check above code either you filter the listings array list or directly modify the  HTML code, Please have a look above both solution, Please let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply to use *ngIf to check if the listing is greater than 0.

Thanks to those that got the idea going...

```
 <div class="content-box" *ngIf="listing.price > 0">
            <a routerLink="/listings/{{listing.id}}">
                <h3>{{listing.name}} - ${{listing.price}}</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
```